# Paypal Checkout (javascript) Create Order - How to fill the shipping name and email?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'm trying to find **how to fill the shipping informations in paypal** and especially the customer's email address and name.

Here is my code :

```
 paypal.Buttons({
      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    reference_id: "PUHF",
                description: "Some description",

                custom_id: "Something7364",
                soft_descriptor: "Great description 1",
                amount: {
                    currency_code: "EUR",
                    value: "234.00",
                    breakdown: {
                        item_total: {
                            currency_code: "EUR",
                            value: "200.00"
                        },
                        tax_total: {
                            currency_code: "EUR",
                            value: "20.00"
                        },
                        discount: { 
                            currency_code: "EUR",
                            value: "5.00"
                        },
                        shipping: {
                            currency_code: "EUR",
                            value: "20.00"
                        },
                        insurance: {
                            currency_code: "EUR",
                            value: "1.00"
                        },
                        shipping_discount: {
                            currency_code: "EUR",
                            value: "2.00"
                        }
                    }
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        name: "Item 1",
                        description: "The best item ever",
                        sku: "xyz-2654",
                        unit_amount: {
                            currency_code: "EUR",
                            value: "100.00"
                        },
                        quantity: "1"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Item 2",
                        description: "Not bad too",
                        sku: "zdc-3942",
                        unit_amount: {
                            currency_code: "EUR",
                            value: "50.00"
                        },
                        quantity: "2"
                    }
                ],
                shipping: {
                    address: {
                        name: {
                            given_name: 'Jean',
                            surname: 'Martin'
                        },
                        email_address: 'jeanmartin[at]email.com',
                        address_line_1: "218 rue de la liberté",
                        address_line_2: "",
                        admin_area_2: "Paris",
                        admin_area_1: "",
                        postal_code: "75000",
                        country_code: "FR",
                    }
                }
                }]
            });
        },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                // Show a success message to the buyer
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
            });
        }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

The shipping address is well filled but the name and email address are not filled in paypal page.

Is someone can help me to pass the right parameters to paypal please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            payer: {
                name: {
                    given_name: 'Jean',
                    surname: 'Martin'
                },
                email_address: 'jeanmartin@email.com'
            },
            purchase_units: [{
                ...
            }]
        });
    },
```

Comment: It works, thank you ! However, if the payer changes his name on paypal pages, the shipping name is changed in the same way. Is there a way to keep the shipping name even if the payer changes his name ?